# usage of "it all"

Tags: word-usage

[From a tutorial (Transcript)](https://youtu.be/cX2dMKYYZI4?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=18)

> Although we hadn't planned everything perfectly, **it all** went
> as smoothly as anyone could expect.

I understand the meaning of the whole sentence: speaker is making a comparison to emphasize everything is okay.

I don't understand the usage of "it all". "It" might refer to a party, meeting or other event in question, what does "all" do there?

Comment: The referent of *it all* cannot be determined from the single sentence. It's missing essential context that can only come from a previous sentence that's missing.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. Would you please help me to make up a context? The quotation doesn't have more context even in that tutorial.

Comment: As far as the exercise was concerned, there was no need for any context. Knowing what *it all* referred to wasn't the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It all" just refers to "*everything*". The types of "things," though, depend on context. Here are some examples.

> Friend 1: How was your trip to France?
>
> Friend 2: It was awesome! The Eiffel Tower, the Louvre; I saw **it all**! *(every tourist attraction)*

> Police officer 1: He keeps saying he didn't do it.
>
> Police officer 2: Yeah, yeah. I've heard **it all** before. *(every story about innocence)*

In terms your sentence, I would say the meaning of *it all* is

> Although we hadn't planned everything perfectly, **every event that was supposed to happen** went as smoothly as anyone could expect.